# Best way to rephrase the sentence (if needed)

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm not sure if this is a correct section for this.

After writing and reviewing my sentence multiple times, I ended up with following:

> And yet, instead of succumbing to a fit of uncontrollable panic, I was feeling serene.

To me, the above example sounds a bit weird. But I'm not a native language user, so it might me because of that.

**Is there any way I should restructure that sentence, or is it fine as is?**

Please let me know if I need to provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**serene**   [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176389?rskey=r78ivz&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)  adj

Slight modification to your sentence:

> And yet, instead of succumbing to a fit of uncontrollable panic, I was
>   serene.

As in:

> “He remained serene in the midst of turbulence”

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/serene)

and

> “I am as serene as the rainbow,” parliamentary budget committee
>   chairman Claudio Borghi tweeted on Aug. 13. Wall Street Journal Aug
>   18, 2018

Serene does not necessarily need the'feeling'.

Comment: I was hesitant between serene and mellow. Which one is better in that context?

Comment: I like serene, but mellow is good too!

Comment: So in both cases it would be 'was serene/mellow'?

Comment: ... yes it would.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no problem of structure, if by that you mean grammar.  And the sentence is not weird.  The fact that you feel uneasy about it is a sign of real fluency.

The source of your unease is the meaning.

Take

> “.. instead of succumbing to a fit of panic, “ ...

Succumbing is something you do: a fit of panic is presented as something to be resisted, and (we  find in the rest of the sentence) has been resisted.

So the corresponding end to the sentence would state not something you felt but something you did.

> Instead of succumbing to a fit of panic, I remained calm.

If, on the other hand, you wanted to focus the reader’s attention on your feelings, it might go more like this:

> Instead of being overwhelmed by panic, I was feeling serene.

But this is no more than a suggestion.